# Playwright - drag and drop with offset

Tags: typescript, drag-and-drop, ui-automation, playwright

We have a CodeceptJS automation framework using Playwright webdriver and application under test is in Typescript. Is there a way to drag and drop an element to a particular location on the page? I want to be able to drag and drop either horizontally or vertically by a certain pixels. The current dragAnddrop() Playwright method brings the draggable element back to its original position as I'm not able to drag it long enough to drop it in placeholder.
Something like what selenium has dragdrop(dragFrom, dragTo, offsetX);

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got the same probleme here.
Try with this code:

```
const dataTransfert = await page.evaluateHandle(() => new DataTransfert());
await page.dispatchEvent('.fc-daygrid-day-events', 'dragstart', { dataTransfert });
await page.dispatchEvent('.fc-day-today', 'drop', { dataTransfert });
```

Tell me if it works for you.